# How many div class=col-* to place inside a row div in bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I want to create a layout using bootstrap having two columns for tablets, 3 for desktops and 4 for large desktops.

I don't understand how many divs to put inside one row.

What is the proper code? And Why?

This?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change number of columns depending on screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736084/change-number-of-columns-depending-on-screen-size)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's `row` is essentially **12 columns**.

This means your examples don't really have the exactly correct approach on column values, but you don't have to put all the size-specifications in anyways.

You can do the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
```

With this example, the three columns would stick together, side-by-side until the md-breakpoint (which is around 992 pixels width) and then, the two first columns will pop out side-by-side, while the third one drops to fill the entire screen width below those two.

Another example:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

So there will be two columns side-by-side until the width drops below 992px, then the two columns in the middle will be 8/4, while the other two get the full width.

There is no real limit on the number of columns, but **you should make sure the column width values in each viewport (xs, sm, md, lg) make up a total of 12** or that exact value multiplied with, for example, two.

Comment: but if i need to show 50 records, can i put 50 column's div inside ONE div row? or i have to repeat a div row each x div columns? i need to understand the value of x.

Comment: You can basically just spam `col-md-4`'s and display unlimited amount of column content. The only problem you'll probably be facing is the height of those columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

In your first example will put 2 columns per row in small screens.
3 columns per row in medium sized screens. And 4 columns in large sized screens. A bootstrap row is filled with 12 columns in total. So this should be the one for your intended use case.

Be sure to reset the CSS of your application at the beginning so you do not get any weird margins or paddings.

Answer (score 0):

To put 50 divs inside a row you need to use nested columns. see the below example..You can have as many columns as you want inside a single div...go full screen to see the effect as I have used `col-lg-*`. For other screen sizes use `col-md-* col-sm-* col-xs-*` use all of them together t make your design responsive.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:red;">
<div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:blue;">
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:brown;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:cyan;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
cheers!
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:green;">
<div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:brown;">

cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:cyan;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:brown;">

cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:cyan;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
cheers!
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:black;">
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:brown;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:cyan;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
cheers!
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:brown;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:cyan;">
cheers!
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
cheers!
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!